# How to get Complete DateTime in a given culture for Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, cultureinfo

My requirement is to get DateTime in given locale and I am trying to achieve this by using below code

```
var d1 = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-NZ");
var da = d1.ToString("d1", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Output" + da);

output: Friday, 15 January 2021 11:55 pm
```

Its working fine for some cultures like "to,en-NZ,en-AU,de-DE" but its not working for "fr-CA, en-CA"

```
var d1 = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
var da = d1.ToString("d1", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Output" + da);

Output: 15 janvier 2021 23:55
```

For Fr-CA and en-CA ** I am not getting Day of week**

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#, datetime formatting, mont name, cultureinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744760/c-datetime-formatting-mont-name-cultureinfo)

Comment: No. Still i am facing issue fro these cultures fr-CA and en-CA

Comment: They should work https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1AdQW

Comment: Its worked with your link. but as per my code, it should work for every culture. right? Am I missing any thing in my code

Comment: Show us your actual code, if you paste your code to a new console app you'll see it won't get the output you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that day of the week is not showing is my application is running on .NET framework so framework/.NETCore3.1/.. do not support day of the week for all cultures

If we run the same application on .NET5, its supports day of the week for all cultures